# select date column greater then specific

Tags: sql, firebird

I have the following criteria in `where` clause:

```
cat_product.datetime > '2012-09-18 11:24:54'
```

In the result:

```
18.09.2012 11:24:54
18.09.2012 11:34:51
18.09.2012 12:07:12
```

The problem in that the result contain  `18.09.2012 11:24:54`. Why? In the criteria write `>` operator not `>=`.

Comment: Maybe you have differences between milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with milliseconds.
Needs to convert to a format which do not have miliseconds.
Such as :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),120)
```

For you, it should be something like:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, cat_product.datetime,120) > '2012-09-18 11:24:54'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

cat_product.datetime > fmtdate('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss','2012-09-18 11:24:54')