# Select rows base on their date

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, firebird

I am selecting `SUM` for a column if row meets with some condition but the problem is that one of the conditions must be that date is less then today's date.

I am using 1 command string on 4 connection string (4 different databases for 4 years)

I have looked into [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492960/select-date-column-greater-then-specific) question but I do not get it how I should do it.

Currently I have this command:

`SELECT SUM(UPLACENO) FROM DOKUMENT WHERE VRDOK = 15 AND FLAG = 1 AND KODDOK = 0`

And this is how I use it:

```
FbConnection con1..... //this year
{
    FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(commandUpAbove);
    ....
}

FbConnection con2..... //year before
{
    FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(commandUpAbove);
    ....
}

FbConnection con3..... //2 years before
{
    FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(commandUpAbove);
    ....
}

FbConnection con2..... //3 years before
{
    FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(commandUpAbove);
    ....
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is:

1. how to select row where column `DATUM` (datetime) is less than `myDate` (dd/MM)
2. Since I am using same command in 4 databases, how I can manage to tell it to select `where date < mydate` but without giving him year

Each database is for 1 year period (01.01 - 31.12 of one year).

Comment: Pass the required date as a parameter, subtracting required number of years from todays date/time. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992451/how-to-subtract-a-year-from-the-datetime

Comment: Are they actually 4 different databases?  Are you able to change that?

Comment: What date?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: They are 4 different databases and It works but what I do not know is how I can use one command string for all years where date need to be less than let's say '31.01'

Comment: Look at edited question

Comment: You don't want to compare year?

Comment: No. I do not want to compare them

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output. And please at least post your attempt to write a query that does this. Stack Overflow is not a free code service, we expect some effort from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
string commandUpAbove = "SELECT SUM(UPLACENO) FROM DOKUMENT WHERE VRDOK = 15 AND FLAG = 1 AND KODDOK = 0 AND DATUM < '?';";
```

For each of your queries use:

```
FbConnection con1..... 
{
   FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(commandUpAbove.Replace("?", mydate.ToString()));
    ....
}
```

Edit: As has been pointed out in the comments, this should only be used if mydate is defined in code. If the user enters the mydate in a text box, then DON'T use this. Instead, mydate should be a DateTime of some kind. There are also other, often faster or better ways to insert parameters to the sql command.

Comment: this approach is both fragile, insecure and somewhat slow - http://bobby-tables.com/ - instead one has to use parameters, strongly typed. Like the example #2 at https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-examples-of-use/

Comment: Alternatively one may see "query with parameters" examples at http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/lcpi_oledb_net__using_adonet_with_firebird.html

Comment: Don't use a literal string with a question mark, use real parameters (which is a question mark without quotes...

Comment: `if mydate is defined in code` - bad even then: makes the code fragile lacking type safety, is binding to specific SQL server and its idea about date literals format (which may be changed later), and makes SQL queries recompiled again and again for every row. Parametrized prepared queries, which gets executed without recompilation with only a variable being changed, is a proper way